# Detect BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE error when instantiating a driver with WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I am creating a new Appium WebDriver session using WebdriverIO API:

```
const options = {...};
const driver: Browser<"async">;

try {
    driver = await remote(options);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
}
```

In BrowserStack there is a limit on the number of parallel tests that one can run. I am hitting that limit and my call to `remote` errors and, in the catch, I get this inside variable `error`:

```
Failed to create session.
```

Which does not give me much info on why the call failed. On the other hand, the driver is emitting logs that give such an answer:

```
XXXX-XX-XXTXX:XX:XX.XXXZ ERROR webdriver: [BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE] All parallel tests are currently in use, including the queued tests. Please wait to finish or upgrade your plan to add more sessions.: [BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE] All parallel tests are currently in use, including the queued tests. Please wait to finish or upgrade your plan to add more sessions.
    at Object.getErrorFromResponseBody (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:189:12)
    at /home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:168:31
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:9:103)
    at _next (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:11:194)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

### Question

How can I get more information about the nature of the error as I am calling `remote`? I want to detect the occurrence of `BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE` so that I can implement, in code, some strategies around this issue (like retrying after some randomized time).

Answer (score 0):

The error `BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE` indicates that all your running threads and queued threads are full and no more test can be triggered.

Once you have maxed out your running + queued threads, any new sessions initiated are dropped with `BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE`.

You will not be able to trigger any more tests until there are threads available.

You can take a look at https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites/ by setting `maxInstances`. This will allow you to limit the number of tests triggered.

Comment: Yes I understand your point and thanks for the answer, but I am afraid you missed the point here. I want, in code, to get details about this specific error so I can take some action. Also your point is valid if the WebdriverIO is being use as test runner, which is not what i am doing and cannot do fomr a series of reasons :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is a proper `Error` object and has `message` and `stack` available. The log shown is encapsulated in the message, so the following is just fine:

```
try {
    driver = await remote(options);
} catch (error) {
    if (error.message.indexOf("BROWSERSTACK_ALL_PARALLELS_IN_USE") >= 0) {
        // Retry
    }
    // Do something else
}
```